# "SDK location not found" android error with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, apk

I've been reading a lot, nothing is working, already tried:

- write skd.dir = /home/fxn/Android/Sdk in the local.properties file
- move that file to the project's root
- set the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable

I just want to build a simple testing React Native app in apk file, I was following the instructions of the [React docs](https://react-mongolia.github.io/react-native/docs/next/signed-apk-android) and everything was fine, until I got this issue.

Here is the entire error log

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/fxn/node/reactNative/Test/node_modules/react-native- 
reanimated/android/build.gradle' line: 89

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or 
by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 
'/home/fxn/node/reactNative/Test/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to 
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

Answer (score 0):

In the System Variable section, click New. In the VariableName, enter ANDROID_HOME, and at the next input, the SDK path.

[First do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RxP9.png)
[and second, do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDFSV.png)

Comment: i'm a linux user